# Solr search query with special character not working in Sitecore

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.2

I have content on page like "financial rate is 3.75% and market....." . Now, if i entered search keyword as "3.75%" then result should display this page but it is not working. It is returning 0 result but it is working fine when i enter "3.75" as search keyword.

```
public SearchResults<SearchHelper> GetSearchData(string searchtext)
    {

        using (searchContext)

        {

            //Fetch all items which contains search query                

            var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchHelper>().OrderByDescending(i => i.BoostingValue).Where(i => (i.PageSearchContent.Contains(searchtext) ));

            var result = query.GetResults();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help that how can i allow search with special character ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use **WordDelimiterFilterFactory** filter to convert **%** to **DIGITAL** or **ALPHA**

For example:

```
# A customized type mapping for WordDelimiterFilterFactory
# the allowable types are: LOWER, UPPER, ALPHA, DIGIT, ALPHANUM, SUBWORD_DELIM
# 
# the default for any character without a mapping is always computed from 
# Unicode character properties

# Map the $, %, '.', and ',' characters to DIGIT 
# This might be useful for financial data.
% => DIGIT
( => ALPHA
) => ALPHA
. => DIGIT
```

**An example of usage**

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" types="wdfftypes.txt" generateNumberParts="0" stemEnglishPossessive="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" generateWordParts="1" splitOnNumerics="1"/>
```

Just create a new file called "wdfftypes.txt" in solr/coreName/conf/wdfftypes.txt

Comment: Thanks for your Reply.
i have applied suggestion given by you but it is not working.
i did all above change then rebuild index in Sitecore for Master and Web. i have modified filter in index and query analyzer.

Comment: @ChirayuBrahmbhatt Could you please me what does analysis say? 
Verbose Output should point you in the right direction to see the "char" type.

Comment: i am able to see for %.. type:Word